# ParamQuery Grid (pqgrid) updateRow with dynamic values for keys

Tags: object, dynamic, key

I have a huge problem with ParamQuery. I'm using the updateRow method for update a row below the documentation:

```
$( ".selector" ).pqGrid( "updateRow", 
    { rowIndx: 2, row: { 'ProductName': 'Cheese', 'UnitPrice': 30 } );
```

However I need that 'ProductName', 'UnitPrice', etc.. etc... will be programmatically read from an array of values. How can I do it?

For example if my array at position 2 contains ProductName it's not possible to do

```
$( ".selector" ).pqGrid( "updateRow", 
    { rowIndx: 2, row: { **myArray[2]**: 'Cheese', 'UnitPrice': 30 } );
```

Any ideas?
thanks in advance.

**Solution**

```
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
var key   = myarray[i];
var val   = '44';
obj[key] = val;
}

$( ".selector" ).pqGrid( "updateRow",
rowIndx: 2,
row: obj
});
```

thanks anyway :)